# While installing OpenBlender in Ubuntu, how do I solve "package 'httr' is not available for R version X.X.X" when it IS available?

Tags: r

I have R version 3.6.1 and I'm trying to install package OpenBlender by running:

```
install.packages("openblender")
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository openblender/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'openblender/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package 'httr' is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

But the 'httr' [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/) states that this version IS supported.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to run **on your terminal**:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Then run **on R**:

```
install.packages('openssl')
install.packages('curl')
install.packages('openblender')
```

You should be able to install it now.